# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 setup blocked

Tags: setup, visual-studio-2015

While installing Visual Studio Community 2015, the setup was blocked and I received a message that told me that Visual Studio was already installed.

> Visual Studio Professional 2015 is currently installed on this machine. Please uninstall Visual Studio Professional 2015 and retry.

[image: Screenshot from my PC]

Comment: Sounds like you already have Visual Studio installed

Comment: @Ramhound but this is not really because I've uninstall it and removed all related files !!

Comment: @AhmedHillal There could be registry entries as well as the files. If the installer gave you a "Repair" option, I suggest you use that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Unfortunately no option for repair just that appeared :(

Comment: @AhmedHillal You could try a third-party uninstaller/cleanup utility such as [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download_compare.html) (I have no experience of it myself). N.B. Perform a full backup first, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've iobit Uninstaller it's similar for that program which you've mentioned but still the same

Comment: @AhmedHillal [Force uninstall of Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28731368/1115360) might help. Also, have you tried creating a new user account and installing it in that?